# Python Kivy GridLayout, positioning

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTD9.png)

Hello all, I am new on kivy and can't get results I expect.

:
title: "Test"
GridLayout:
rows:2
cols:2
spacing: 20
canvas.before:
Color:
rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
Rectangle
size: self.size
pos: self.pos

```
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:2
        size: 200, 200
        size_hint: None, None

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2

            Button:
                text: "test0-1"
                size: 100, 100
                size_hint: None, None
            Button:
                text: "test0-2"
                size: 100, 100
                size_hint: None, None
        Button:
            text: "test01-1"
            size: 200, 100
            size_hint: None, None

    Button:
        text: "test1"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 500
```

Answer (score 0):

:
title: "Test"
GridLayout:
rows:1
cols:2
#spacing: 20
canvas.before:
Color:
rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
Rectangle
size: self.size
pos: self.pos

```
    GridLayout:
        rows:2
        cols:1
        size: 200, root.size[1]
        size_hint: None, None
        #pos_hint:{"x":1,"y":1}

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "test0-1"
                size: 100, 100
                size_hint: None, None
            Button:
                text: "test0-2"
                size: 100, 100
                size_hint: None, None

        Button:
            text: "test01-1"
            size: 200, root.size[1] - 100
            size_hint: None, None


    Button:
        text: "test1"
        #size_hint: .7
        #size: 500, 500[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).